# Running into issues with looping the calculation of # of digits in a number

Tags: python

My assignment requires me to take in an input, determine how many digits are in said input, then spit it back out. we are not allowed to use string conversion in order to determine the length of the input. I've managed to get that to work properly. My issue is that I'm supposed to have it repeat in a loop until a sentinel is reached. Here's my code so far.

```
print("This program determines the number of digits in a number.")
print("Enter a number, or 0 to quit.")
count = 0
num = 1
final = 0

num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
while num != 0:
    num = num //10
    count += 1
print("There are", count, "digits in", num)
```

I'm also seeming to have trouble with having my input integer print properly, but it might just be my ignorance there. I've cut out what my attempts at looping it were, as they all seemed to just break the code even more. Any help is welcome, even criticism! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Do you know how to use loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, that is a strange way to get the digits in the number. There's no need to modify the actual number. Just cast the int back to a string and get the length (don't just keep the original string, it could have spaces or something in it which would throw off the count). That is the number of digits.

Secondly, you can do all the work in the loop. There's no need for setup variables, incrementing, a second loop, or anything like that. The key insight is the loop should run forever until you break out of it, so you can just use "while True:" for the loop, and break if the user inputs "0".

```py
print("This program determines the number of digits in a number.")
print("Enter a number, or 0 to quit.")

def find_digits(num):
    count = 0
    while num != 0:
        num = num //10
        count += 1
    return count
    count += 1

# loop forever
while True:
    # hang onto the original input
    text_input = input("Enter a number: ")
    # cast to int - this will throw an exception if the input isn't int-able
    # you may want to catch that
    num = int(text_input)
    # the number of digits is the length of the int as a string
    num_digits = find_digits(num)
    if num == 0:
        print("Goodbye.")
        # "break" manually ends the loop
        break
    # if we got to this point, they didn't input 0 and the input was a number, so
    # print our response
    print(f"There are {num_digits} digits in {num}.")
```

Comment: Hello Charles! I forgot to mention that we aren't allowed to use string conversion to determine the length of the input.

Comment: That's fine, you can just replace my code to find num_digits with yours. That's an advantage to splitting each line into one specific action - it makes it easy to change the implementation. You could even write the digit-finding code in a function, so this code has no idea *how* it is found.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect that requirement.

Comment: Please accept this answer if it's working for you! :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem with printing the input integer correctly is, that you first save it in the num variable and then constantly change it in your while loop. So the original input is lost of course and in the end it always prints the 0, that ends up in num after the while loop finishes.

You can easily fix it, by saving the input value to another variable, that you don't touch in the loop.

```
print("This program determines the number of digits in a number.")
print("Enter a number, or 0 to quit.")
count = 0
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
numcopy = num
while numcopy != 0:
    numcopy = numcopy // 10
    count += 1
print("There are", count, "digits in", num)
```

Comment: Gotcha! I had tried to save the num variable previously, but I think I was doing it inside the loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Counting is better done with Python builtin functions.

```
len(str(num))
```

will give you number of digits in your number.

Comment: The question is about digit counting algorithm (course assignment); using a python shortcut function doesn't answer the OPs problem.